# Different default values for choices in nested content types

Tags: sharepoint

How set different default values for choices field in nested content types.
Example i need to, parent content type has column "Category" and default values as

- Cat1
- Cat2
- Cat3

And child content type has column "Category" and default values as

- Cat1

When i change the default value in child content type to "Cat1" in parent content type default value also set to "Cat1".
How to make them different?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, maybe you can use folders with default field values (as you can still have a no folder view).

https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/policy-management/2013/02/27/how-to-set-default-column-values-on-a-document-in-sharepoint#.VfkvvhHtlBc

Or maybe you can use a workflow to set the default values according to the ContentTypeId of the item

Edit 09/18

What I did in my case was setting the metadata on template used in the content types. You need to host all those templates in a list containing a column with the exact same name and set the proper value for each template.

Regards